# xml editing backend

Tags: php, xml, content-management-system, scaffolding, backend

I would like to have an xml editing interface for a site's backend.

There are many php based CMSes of varying sizes (my favorite being modx), but for some projects it is just overkill.

The point of this xml management system would be that the user would have a graphical interface for xml file generation, from the browser.

some additional features would be nice too like an image uploader and file manager.

does anyone know of any tools that do that?

--- edit ---

I guess I should mention the purpose too.
I'm looking to create a backend for a flash based website. It would be a nice bonus to have an HTML browser-able site too, but what I'd really like is a single XML file that can be edited through this back end. I'll play around with getsimple a bit to see what I can do though.

It would be best if the backend acted as a scaffolding to the xml file, and I could set up some rules and fields, that the scaffolding would adhere to. And use WYSIWYG text editing, file uploading/linking, or color pickers.

I like the simplicity of lenya's (Apache java/xml CMS) layout http://lenya.apache.org/index/screenshots.html, though I must admit I haven't been able to try it, just that the first few screenshots look like what I have in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need a
a. wysiwyg rich text editor that saves into a xml-file or
b. an editor for xml-files?

On a. something like the getsimple cms should fit, on b. have a look on XForms (see http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/wiki/XForms_Implementations)

Comment: Ideally, it would be both. I've looked at getsimple yesterday. Looks impressive, and would have been nice to know about it when I was on a hunt for a flat file cms, but I wish it was able to use one xml file

Answer (score 2):

Try Orbeon which is based on Exist.

It has a form builder using XForms (as Andreas suggested) but translates them to AJAX (from memory).

http://www.orbeon.com/

http://exist.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

[Xopus](http://xopus.com) is a browser based XML editor that you can use for this.
Apache Lenya used to have an integration with Xopus, but I don't know the status of that.

Xopus is used to drive the (Dutch) [flash](http://www.rijksmuseum.nl/formats/container_nl.html) content on the [Rijksmuseum](http://www.rijksmuseum.nl) website.

Disclaimer: I work at Xopus.